# Can sparql count the same statement of triples?

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology, fuseki, triples

I want to count triples with the same statement , is that possible?

I have an turtle file of ontology , and i want to count the triples in apache jena fuseki server.

for an example , i have some triples like this :

```
###  http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2022/11/Papua#pemerintah
:pemerintah rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                     :Topik ;
            :melakukan :positif ;
            :melalui :positif ;
            :meluncurkan :positif ;
            :membangun :positif ;
            :menegaskan :positif ;
            :mengalokasikan :positif ;
            :mengedepankan :positif ;
            :sejahterahkan :positif ;
            :sejahterahkan :positif ;
            :sejahterahkan :positif ;
            :sejahterahkan :positif ;
            :sejahterahkan :positif ;
            :sejahterahkan :positif .
```

Can i count how many triples for :pemerintah :sejatherahkan :positif ?
when i count it , is the result is 6 or just 1?
And can you show me how to count that?

Comment: that doesn't work, an RDF graph is a **set** of triples - once you load the RDF file, the duplicate triples will be lost

Comment: all other things can be counted with SPARQL aggregate function `count`